# How does PhD admissions committee look at my old gre score after starting my Masters

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, gre

I am currently an international Masters student studying at a US university and I'm in the process of applying to several computer science PhD programs in North America. I didn't have the chance to retake the GRE exam to increase my score. I'm wondering how the PhD admissions committee takes into consideration my 3-year-old GRE score... will they give it less weight given that I've already started my Masters, or will they treat it exactly as if I have just took the GRE exam?

Comment: What was your score? If it's baseline for acceptance I would retake. If it's strong I wouldn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience from the perspective of a committee, but I believe that the general way to look at it is that the GRE scores, no matter how old they are, are simply another part of your application package, regardless of timing.

There is no difference in consideration for undergraduates if their GRE is new or from their freshman year; I would imagine that there is no difference that you took your test before your Master's.

Comment: Sorry but as soon as I read your statement "I do not have experience from the perspective of a committee" I stopped processing/believing what you wrote afterwords.